# Copy the fifth value from a specific cell in an Excel spreadsheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, web-scraping, xlsm

I would like to use the df.iloc command to extract the 5th value from the cell.

The cell contains the following value:

UTM ETRS 89 zone 32N

I just want the value "32N" from the cell.

What would I need to add to the command to just output "32N".

df.loc[1,"Coordinate System"]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem.

df.loc[1, "Koordinaten System"].split()[4]

zonefeld.send_keys(df.loc[1, "Koordinaten System"].split()[4])